# Mysql insert text statement with quotation marks in the content

Tags: php, mysql, insert

```
$title = Hello my name is "Title";

$DB->Execute('INSERT INTO page (title) VALUES (?)', array($title));
```

I'm inserting more than one field, but I've removed them just to simplify the example.

I'm running this SQL in my PHP file but I end up with the title being saved as:

> Hello my name is "Title&Qu

How can I save this as intended?

Comment: Aren't you missing some quotes around `$title = Hello my name is "Title";`? So it would be `$title = 'Hello my name is "Title"';`

Comment: Does the title column only allow a certain amount of characters in it?

Comment: @Rasclatt The solution was length. I have no idea why I didn't put that together. I was stuck in looking for some syntax issue in the way I was inserting it. Thanks a lot, if you want to write out your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I have answered it more clearly as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely the answer lies how many characters can be inserted into your `title` column in your database. It's splitting the entity for your double quote (`"`) in half. In your database it's probably written:

```
Hello my name is &quot;Title&qu
```

Expanding the `title` to allow more characters will allow for the:

```
Hello my name is &quot;Title&quot;
```